# Laravel 5.6 module issue

Tags: laravel, module

I have installed `nwidart/laravel-modules`on my localhost for working in modules. But when I am using `php artisan module:make <module-name>` this command for make module I am getting `There are no commands defined in the "module" namespace` this error. After add following

```
$app->configure('modules');
$app->register(\Nwidart\Modules\LumenModulesServiceProvider::class);
```

The code in `bootstrap/app.php` file I am getting `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::configure()` this error.

Comment: read doc of this library

Comment: @AdamKozlowski I have read the documentation and followed the doc but getting same error.

Comment: Don't get your hopes up to build *modular* app, how are you going to solve dependencies (of modules to each other)...